# Selfie stick button causes google now to listen

Tags: google-now, motorola

I am using motorola E (2nd gen). i have a selfie stick with audio jack port. when i attach the selfie stick, and hit the button on the stick, it displays a window where it says

> listening...

and then says

> tap mic to start listening

I tried disabling google now(as i dont use it). but still no luck.
any help will be appreciated.

-thanx

Answer (score 1):

It's a few months late but I just had the same issue on my Nexus 6p. If you're still having the issue and you're rooted I have a solution.

First thing yr gonna have to do is download this app scanCode from your selfie stick.
https://github.com/chrisboyle/keytest/downloads
Run the app, press the button on your selfie stick, and it should show a **scanCode**in there. Mine was **582**

Next step
You have to edit one or more files in **/system/usr/keylayout**. The first file is **Generic.kl**, you will have to search through all the files in that folder to find other instances of your scanCode. I also found **582** in **Vendor_046d_Product_b501.kl**.

In both files search for your scanCode. After that should be some other instruction that is causing your phone to do the voice search, change that to VOLUME_UP

In mine it looked like this in both files

```
key 582 VOLUME_UP
```

When you're done remember to save the files, and make sure its done in all files you it was found in. It won't work otherwise. Reboot and you should be good.